# change column class in bootstrap 4 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a form in Bootstrap 4 and I'm using the grid to determine the width of my input boxes. I have 5 input boxes split on a md and higher viewport as:

col-md-2 col-md-2 col-md-2 col-md-2 col-md-4

I then have some jQuery that hides the 4th column (addClass('d-none')) and changes the 3rd column to col-md-4 (removeClass('col-md-2') and addClass('col-md-4')).

I expected all other columns to remain the same width and in the same spot, but for some reason the entire container becomes smaller and all the elements shift to the left. You can see a sample of what I mean here:
https://codepen.io/ijamal/pen/qoQKPy

```
$("[name='search_type'").on("change", function (e) {
    if ($(this).val() == "oneway") {
        $("#return0").parent().addClass("d-none");
        $("#depart0").parent().removeClass("col-md-2");
        $("#depart0").parent().addClass("col-md-4");
    }
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.closest()`

```
$("#return0").closest('parent_element_here').addClass("d-none");
```

Also, how about some dynamic CSS to inspire you?

These apply style to an entire column. Header, body and footer can be styled separately.

Additionally, you can use these dynamic names in your jQuery

CSS FOR Table Header TH (column 1)

```
/* TABLE > "COLUMN" (..thead > tr > th) - HIDE/SHOW */
/* STYLE > (by ID) */
table thead tr th:nth-child(1) {

}
```

CSS FOR Table Body TD (column 1)

```
/* TABLE > "COLUMN" (..tbody > tr > td) - HIDE/SHOW */
/* STYLE > (by ID) */
table tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {

}
```

CSS FOR Table Footer TH (column 1)

```
/* TABLE > "COLUMN" (..tfoot > tr > th) - HIDE/SHOW */
/* STYLE > (by ID) */
table tfoot tr th:nth-child(1) {

}
```

Comment: appreciate the answer, but the issue was not that d-none wasn't getting applied, it was just that after being applied, the normally static col-x divs were adjusting their widths

Answer (score 0):

turns out the <div class="form-inline"> was causing the issues. I had initially coded the inputs in a single div (form inline) but realized I wanted to control the width, so moved to the grid format and forgot to remove the form-inline. This caused some havoc with the widths and spacing.